# How to flag answers with code but no explanation

Tags: discussion, answers, flags

Quite often, I come across answers that look something like this:

[image: Answer with a single line of unformatted awk code]

They might provide the correct answer, or an answer that solves the OP's problem, but it's just code, with no explanation to how/why it works.

Which flag should I use for these kinds of answers?  Or should they have any flag at all?

The only appropriate one I can think of is the **very low quality** flag.

[image: Flag dialog description of the VLQ flag]

Comment: I'm not sure these need to be flagged. Maybe just downvote.

Comment: Got it.  From reading the duplicate links I can see the consensus is to comment, maybe downvote, but not flag.